# Error grok pattern

Tags: logstash-grok

I want to parse this log and get back only two elements (2016-05-26T10:40:39,513 babacar).

My log is :

> 2016-05-26T10:40:39,513 INFO  [00000003] babacar - NOTE: Unable to
>   open SASUSER.PROFILE. WORK.PROFILE will be opened instead.

But my filter does not work. Help please

```
logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } filter { grok{ match=>{"message"=>"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:datecreer} %{WORD}"} } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:datecreer} %{WORD} \[%{INT}\] %{DATA:app_name} - %{GREEDYDATA}`. You can test your grok patterns at http://grokconstructor.appspot.com

Comment: Thanks pancake. I want Get back the first one and the last line.                         2016-05-26T10:40:39,513 INFO  [00000003] ngoalfe - NOTE: Unable to open SASUSER.PROFILE. WORK.PROFILE will be opened instead.
2016-05-26T10:40:39,513 INFO  [00000003] ngoalfe - NOTE: All profile changes will be lost at the end of the session.
2016-05-26T10:40:39,513 INFO  [00000003] ngoalfe - 
2016-05-26T10:40:39,605 INFO  [00000006] ngoalfe - NOTE: Copyright (c) 2002-2010 by SAS Institute Inc., Cary, NC, USA. Can i do that with grok filter ?

Comment: Edited so you only get the two elements back.